# Complex SQL table update with RegEx's in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am pulling unstructured data from a source and I am trying to put in structured from in DB.  To minimize the amount of overhead by bombarding my server with multiple queries, i was wondering if there is a way to do a complex query that:
Searches a string for a regex pattern say A[0-9]G+
and add a new row in another table where row.column = found column from regex

Comment: You might want to provide some more info.  Such as an example of your data and an example of the output you expect.

Comment: I guess what I really want is to SELECT the regex substrings from a column (there may be multiple).  For example: User1 says Hey check out #hashtag1 #hashtag2 #hashtag3, i want 3 row returned: (user1,hashtag1) (user1,hashtag2), (user1,hashtag3)

Comment: Also you might want to state exactly how the data is getting to your MySql server.  There might be better options than running regex in the database itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has an INSERT-SELECT statement that lets you combined a selection (as complex as you want, including regex) with an insertion into a table of whatever was selected.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html